# Who are the people who help with "Let Sleeping Mountains Lie"?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Early on in Final Fantasy XV's "Let Sleeping Mountains Lie" quest, you visit a location where a bunch of NPCs you have met throughout your travels gather together to help you out. (I previously said this was the first thing that happens in post-game content, but apparently that was a mistake. It's just common, not the actual quest trigger.)

When I got there, the game told me I had met "13 of a possible 14" of them. Of course, instead of thinking "awesome, I did a pretty good job," I thought "who did I miss?!" So, who are the 14 people you can meet there in the diner? I tried looking it up, but the guides I found just gloss over this, saying little more than "a group of NPCs exists, visit them" before skipping ahead to strategy for the more complicated later part of the quest.

As a follow-up, what are the conditions for making each NPC appear (I know it's not necessarily "complete the quest chain" because at least two of them still had more stuff to do) and what do they give you when you're there?

Comment: Good question, I had the exact same number and reaction!

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5mmzc4/where_can_i_find_a_list_of_the_14_friends/) reddit post lists the 14, but it doesn't list the conditions for making them appear. I would expect it would be to complete the full (or partial) of their quest lines

Comment: @Wondercricket, it definitely isn't the full quest line. I don't even know if you have to complete any of the quests. I had Sonia appear and I never spoke to her again after doing her very first "find these frogs" quest.

Comment: If this quest is for the "Let the sleeping mountains lie" quest as the link suggests then this question is very misleading. You can pick this quest up long before you the end of the game. I was very confused because I got no phone call when I travelled back to past Lucis after the end game... Assuming that the quest is the let the sleeping mountains lie (which sounds right form the gathering of people) then you should refer to it by name and not with the incorrect and much more roundabout description.

Comment: @Chris Wait, really? I got this immediately after beating the game. I watched a friend get it immediately after beating the game. I talked to two other friends who got it immediately after beating the game. I honestly thought beating the game was the trigger for the quest. I figured I'd write it up this way to keep spoilers as minimal as possible... I'll try to edit.

Comment: I was vastly overlevelled which might be what made the difference (I was level 90ish when I completed the game) so it may be that it unlocks after end game or when you get to level X, whichever comes first...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following are the 14 people, each of which gives you or is involved in a side-quest at one point or another. If they give multiple quests, it isn't necessary to complete them all to trigger their appearance. However I am unsure of how many quests each one needs to have completed to get them to appear, or if you only need to meet and speak to them.

In addition, whilst some of these characters are involved in the main quest, I'm unsure about whether their respective side-quest needs to be activated/ completed if you have already interacted with them through the main story.

> Cid - Engineer met at Hammerhead through the main story
>
> Takka - Chef met at Hammerhead restaurant
>
> Dave - Leader of the Hunters met near Hammerhead through the main story (moves between quests)
>
> Dino - Journalist & jewellery maker met at Galdin Quay through the main story
>
> Coctura - Chef met at Galdin Quay restaurant
>
> Sania - Scientist initially met at Coernix Station - Alstor (moves between quests)
>
> Wiz - Chocobo breeder met at Wiz's Chocobo Outpost
>
> Navyth - Fisherman initially met at a fishing spot in Alstor Slough (moves between quests)
>
> Vyv - Magazine editor met on the Lestallum outlook
>
> Iris - Gladio's sister met in Lestallum through the main quest (later moves to Cape Caem)
>
> Talcott - Young boy met in Lestallum through the main quest (later moves to Cape Caem
>
> Holly - Power plant worker met in Lestallum outside the power plant
>
> Kimya - Runs a shop near the Malmalam Thicket, met through Dave's questline
>
> Ezma - Old woman at at Meldacio Hunter HQ. Need to complete the 8 dungeons that are involved with the Menace Beneath Lucis side-quest in order to speak to her (whilst it isn't necessary to complete the game to activate the "Let Sleeping Mountains Lie" quest, this quest will only trigger once the game is completed)