# Do the 14 people of "Let Sleeping Mountains Lie" help in any way?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Follow up to : [Who are the people who help with "Let Sleeping Mountains Lie"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301924/who-are-the-people-who-help-with-let-sleeping-mountains-lie)

They show you that you could have up to 14 people "helping" you on this quest (as far as I know, it's just talking to you in the diner where you start the quest).

I personally had 12, and now have to go against a level 99 monster.

But is having more or less of these 14 in the diner change the quest? Like if I would have all 14 would the quest be easier? Would having less than I have now make the quest harder?

Does the number of people "helping" you in that diner change the quest at all?

Comment: From my experience, the number of people makes no difference whatsoever. But I don't know for sure, I'll do some research later and write a full answer if no one else does.

Comment: But since they show it, it feels like it makes a difference

Comment: I know each one gives you healing items when you talk to them, so more friends results in more items. Aside from that, I don't think they "help" in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5g9t4u/let_the_sleeping_mountains_lie_quest_question/?st=j6dr6pjz&sh=bd2462dc), getting all 14 will nab you some extra items (including Oracle Ascension coins!) and dialogue, but will have no impact on the actual gameplay.